# Using Postsharp to aspect a constructor

Tags: c#, postsharp, aop

How can I write a PostSharp aspect to apply an attribute to a class? The scenario is Like this:

```
public sample ss()
{
file.create("some file ");
}
```

which can be aspected through

```
[assembly: MyAspect(AttributeTargetAssembly="mscorlib", AttributeTargetTypes="System.IO.File", AttributeTargetMembers="Create"]
```

similarly for the below structure how can we create aspect ?

```
public sample ss()
    {
     StreamWriter sw= new StreamWriter("some file");    
    }
```

is it any possible to do?

waiting for your valuable comments and sugessions

Answer (score 0):

On your Aspect declaration, add the following and it might work:

```
[MulticastAttributeUsage(MulticastTargets.Constructor, TargetMemberAttributes = MulticastAttributes.Instance)]
```